# PCL error in moving least squares

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the Moving Least square code provided in pcl, here is my code exaclty:

```
<iostream>
<pcl/point_types.h>
<pcl/point_cloud.h>
<pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
<pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
<pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
<pcl/surface/mls.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile("KinectPointCloudChest2_filtered.pcd", cloud); // Create a KD-Tree
    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree <pcl::PointXYZ>); 
    // Output has the PointNormal type in order to store the normals calculated by MLS
    pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointNormal> mls_points; 
    // Init object (second point type is for the normals, even if unused)
    pcl::MovingLeastSquares <pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal> mls;
    mls.setComputeNormals(true); // Set parameters
    mls.setInputCloud(cloud.makeShared());
    mls.setPolynomialFit(true);
    mls.setPolynomialOrder(2);
    mls.setSearchMethod(tree);
    mls.setSearchRadius(0.03); // Reconstruct
    mls.process(mls_points);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr mls_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZ>);
    mls_cloud->resize(mls_points.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mls_points.points.size(); ++i) {
        mls_cloud->points.x = mls_points.points.x; //error
        mls_cloud->points.y = mls_points.points.y;
        //error
        mls_cloud->points.z = mls_points.points.z;
        //error
    }
    pcl::io::savePCDFile("KinectPointCloudChest2_mls.pcd", mls_points);
    return 0;
}
```

but I get an error throw pcl::IOException ("[pcl::PCDWriter::writeASCII] Input point cloud has no data!"); what to do in this case?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196572/pcl-error-in-moving-least-squares/) by [sarah.ali.1@ulaval.ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/20681/sarah.ali.1@ulaval.ca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, you'll have more luck with PCL-specific guidance on the PCL boards/mailing list.

If you mean you're following this [tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/resampling.php), everything looks good until you try to run the for loop, where you're not actually indexing into the points array, or even using the mls_cloud object for anything afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/26383/meng/) on 2016-03-24**:
precisely.Do you already have a solution?